# Переменная в имени класса

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
div class="variable"
```

или так:

```
div class="var(--variable)"
```

Как в имя класса впихнуть переменную ? Которой придавать значения разных классов? Это возможно ?

Желательно такую, т.е. CSS:

```
body{--variable;}
```

Есть же тег
`<Var> variable </var>`
В примерах переменные берутся из баз данных. Его можно как-то применить здесь ? Без БД ?

Все мы хотим обойтись без JS. Но если есть возможность на JS, то тоже интересно.

Comment: CSS variable properties только к стилям относятся. Класс менять так document.getElementById('idOfElement').className = 'newClassName';   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576927/how-to-dynamically-change-css-class-of-an-html-tag

Answer (score -3):

Например так:
Создай перемененную

```
const classVariable = 'variable'
```

В разметке укажи:

```
class={classVariable }
```

Comment: что за бред????

Comment: не бред.
Не уточнил, если работаем с реактом, то такой код будет работать
const cardLikeButtonClassName = (`elements__like ${isLiked ? 'elements__like_active' : ''}` );
а в разметке:
<button onClick={handleLikeClick} type="button" className={cardLikeButtonClassName}></button>

Если в чистом JS, то сперва находим элемент
element = document.querySelector(''selector)

потом можем добавить класс
element.classList.add('active')

Comment: а с чего вы решили, что в задании вообще спрашивается про реакт?

Comment: Про react даже не слышал. Я поищу 
свой пример, для которого это потребовалось. Вот Виктор дал простой ответ. Я просто не очень структуру JS знаю.  Получается, все равно надо вводить переменную для имени класса? Или не надо.

Comment: Я понял, что в JS нет путей придать какой-либо переменной значения класса (или нет смысла), а используется прямая замена класса прямо в свойствах стиля.

Comment: Вывод : в чистом CSS нет этого способа. ? Ведь роль условий мог бы исполнять псевдокласс : hover . Это не событие. Это чистый CSS. А событие onmouseover это JS. В JS способ замены класса без переменных известен.